# Как узнать над каким gameobject находится мышь

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть таблица с элементами в unity. Мне надо зафиксировать свайп над элементом в таблице, и в процессе свайпа его передвигать. Я написал скрипт (определяет свайп), который поместил на таблицу. Как из функции update(скрипт на ТАБЛИЦЕ) получить ЭЛЕМЕНТ таблицы, над которым был совершен свайп?

Comment: при первом клике посылайте луч из точки в которой находится мышка.  И с помощью луча проверяйте в какой обьект он попадает

Answer (score 0):

При работе со свайпами используйте библиотеку `UnityEngine.EventSystem` и такие функции как `OnPointerEnter` и `OnPointerExit`. В [этом](https://habr.com/ru/post/359106/) сайте хорошо объяснили и показывали как работают эти функции.